# VSCode - LaTeX workshop extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

Not sure if this the right place to post this question. If not, my apologies.

I have two windows 10 machines. In both I have installed the last version of visual studio code and the last version of LaTeX-Workshop.

In one machine the Latex code shows up with the correct colors, whereas in the other machine it does not. See screenshots below of the first (working) example and of the second (non-working) example of the same code.

I have tried reinstalling LaTeX-Workshop but it didn't result.

**Working example:** 
[image]

**Non-working example:**
[image: NoColor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an incompatibility of the package with some VScode themes.

More info here:  https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/FAQ#syntax-highlighting-does-not-work-for-most-elements

Correct. It works with the ***Dark+ (default dark)*** theme but not with the Dark(Visual Studio).